# How can i count the two-dimesional array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [not_valid_user] => Array
        (
            [] => asdsad
        )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [not_valid_user] => Array
        (
            [] =>  asdasd
        )
    )
)
```

**I need the count of array [not_valid_user]**

For example:

**The above arrays count is 2. How can i get it?**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can the second level arrays contain other keys than the not_valid_user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$invalidUsersFound = 0;
foreach ( $data as $k => $v ) {
  if ( IsSet ( $v['not_valid_user'] ) === true )
    $invalidUsersFound++;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: +1, although I suspect that what he wants would actually require `$invalidUsersFound += count($v['not_valid_user']);` - but the question/example is not really clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is count of all elements in every "not_valid_user" array,

```
$count=0;
foreach($mainArray as $innerArray)
{

 if (isset($innerArray['not_valid_user']) && is_array($innerArray['not_valid_user']))
 { 
    $count += count($innerArray['not_valid_user']);// get the size of the 'not_valid_user' array
 } 
}

echo $count;//Count of all elements of  not_valid_user
```

Comment: +1, although the inner `if`s could be tidied up to `if (isset($innerArray['not_valid_user']) && is_array($innerArray['not_valid_user'])) { $count += count($innerArray['not_valid_user']); }`

Comment: @DaveRandom updated it according to your suggestion. thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$count=0;
foreach($mainArray as $innerArray)
{

if(isset($innerArray['not_valid_user']))
  $count++;
}

echo $count;//Count of not_valid_user

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cnt = 0;

array_map(function ($value) use (&$cnt) {

    $cnt += (int)(isset($value["not_a_valid_user"]));

}, $arr);

echo $cnt;
```

Providing your version of PHP supports anonymous functions.